# Infinite iid sum of standard normal random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Having messed up some probabilistic knowledge, I am confused about how to describe the infinite sum $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} X_t$, where $X_t$'s are iid standard normal random variables.

1. Is it still a "valid" random variable (does the partial sum diverges/converges in some sense, or say, does it make sense to consider a normal variable with an infinite variance)?
2. What can we say about its mean and variance (can we still interchange the expectation and the infinite sum)?

Comment: I don't think the sum is well-defined as a r.v. anymore. That's because the set of infinite sequences of absolutely converging sum should have zero measure...

Comment: It is not meaningful: as an example of what goes wrong, its CDF would have to be $F(x)=\frac12$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, which is not a CDF since it does not approach $0$ or $1$

Comment: If $(X_i)$ is i.i.d then $\sum X_i$ converges  in any sense (almost surely,  in probability or in distribution) if and only if  $X_i=0$ with probability $1$.